# Is there an equivalent of Jira-Releases in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, jira

In Jira, you can create Releases for a project. As part of a Release, you can specify which issues are part of it as well as add Release notes.
These are extremely useful when you have automated build scripts, as the API for JIRA can be queried by the scripts as part of a CD pipeline.
You can therefore do things like (but not limited to):

- Fill in a changelog dynamically
- Stop deployment if there are an issues part of the Release that are not Done
- Retrieve version numbers

Question: Is there a VSTS equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is currently anything directly comparable to a Jira 'release' built into Azure Devops, which would allow you to package up completed Work Items on a board into a 'Release' work item.

You could implement a "poor man's" version of this by creating a [custom process for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#add-or-modify-work-item-types) that included a new 'Release' work item type. Each 'Release work item' could then be manually linked to work items you want to include in that release and could contain custom fields for the 'version' number or any other meta data you wanted to store with that release. This could then later be queried from a CD pipeline which, taking one of your examples, would allow you to do something like iterate over the linked work items for the release and make sure they are in a 'done' status.

**Edit:** As an example of integration techniques, the [REST API for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) supports a simple REST GET request to query all work items in a project for a custom work item type:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?types={YourCustomWorkItemType}&includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=4.1
```

The API will also return any custom fields you have associated with this WIT, listing them under the key 'Custom.{YourFieldName}' within the "fields" object of the WIT response.

If your team was working with sprints, the other potential method I could think of to do this would be for each 'sprint' to become a named version which would become your 'release' once the sprint was complete. Work items that were not implemented as part of that sprint/version/release) would then be moved into the next sprint or closed. I'm not sure this approach would be very sustainable for complex projects.

There are features of interest listed on the [Azure Devops Features Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/) that may improve this workflow in the near future (for example, "Release traceability – Work Item integration", planned for implementation in 2018 Q4), although it's difficult to find out any implementation details.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you might be misunderstanding what I’m asking. I’m not after Azure DevOps equivalents for the scenarios I’ve listed in my question as those are just examples of things you can do with the one JIRA feature that I’m asking about; and that’s a special work item type (if you want to call it that) called a Release. This is not a pipeline; it simply contains release notes (text), release description (text), and a list of issues that are part of the release.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I have completely revised my answer based on your clarification and my re-reading your question properly.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Appreciate the complete revisal :) Yea I had a feeling it would need to be a custom WIT. I guess my next question is, can custom WITs be retrieved via the Rest API?

Comment: ...because with JIRA, you have a /versions endpoint, which gets you the list of releases. I’m guessing it won’t be as simple as a /<custom_WIT> with Azure DevOps API?

Comment: Absolutely, the Azure DevOps REST API supports this, I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: It has been a few years since this question was asked. For anyone looking for this sort of info now, both the pipeline run and the "Environments" area include this sort of information. These items apply to YAML pipelines, less so for the classic pipelines.

Comment: Hello Thomas, can you explain how pipeline and environment include this kind of information, what do you mean by that? as I still not able to find similar way in Azure to manage releases? can you please explain, thanks.